# Jqueryui dialog with multiple languages

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, multilingual

I use jqueryui, dialog plugin with this code for example.

```
$( "#showUser-form" ).dialog(
                    {
                        buttons: {
                            "OK": function()
                            {
                                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                            },
                            cancel: function()
                            {
                                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                            }
                        },
                        close: function() {}
                    });
```

How can I do to be able to change the text of button 'cancel' for example for a multilanguages website ?

Regards

Hugo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a new object to contain the buttons and pass it to the `buttons` parameter.  Then you can dynamically set the text of the buttons.

[jsFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4zHuW/)

Like this:

```
//You can dynamically change button text here
var buttons = [,];
buttons['OK'] = 'OK :)';
buttons['Cancel'] = 'Cancel :(';

var buttonArray = {};
buttonArray[buttons['OK']] = function() {
    //Set OK function here
    $(this).dialog('close');
};
buttonArray[buttons['Cancel']] = function() {
    //Set Cancel function here
    $(this).dialog('close');
};


$(function () {
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        buttons: buttonArray
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I will try ASAP and give you my results.